# git difftool Opens mergetool View

Tags: git

My `.gitconfig` has:

```
...
[merge]
    tool = BeyondCompare4
[diff]
    guitool = beyondcompare4
[difftool "beyondcompare4"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[mergetool "BeyondCompare4"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

However, whenever I run `git difftool ...` the `git mergetool ...` command with the 4-arguments is called and I get the 3-way Merge view instead of the side-by-side view.

How do I get the side-by-side view when using `git difftool`?

Note: I used GitExtensions to set the config file.

Comment: Windows is case insensitive. Try modifying the value of `merge.tool` to `bc4` for example and `[mergetool "BeyondCompare4"]` to `[mergetool "bc4"]`.

Comment: That did the trick!
I changed `[difftool "beyondcompare4"]` to `[difftool "BeyondCompare4"]` Thanks!